# How do I grab the text from two different nodes/elements simultaneously as I am iterating in xslt?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

So I have the XML:

```
<forecast>
        <area aac="NSW_FA001" description="New South Wales" type="region">
            <forecast-period start-time-local="2020-04-13T09:08:07+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-13T09:08:07+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-12T23:08:07Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-12T23:08:07Z">
                <text type="warning_summary_footer">Details of warnings are available on the Bureau's website www.bom.gov.au, by telephone 1300-659-218* or through some TV and radio broadcasts.</text>
                <text type="product_footer">* Calls to 1300 numbers cost around 27.5c incl. GST, higher from mobiles or public phones.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
        <area aac="NSW_ME006" description="Canberra" type="metropolitan" parent-aac="NSW_FA001">
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2020-04-13T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-14T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-12T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-13T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Some high cloud, clearing by the afternoon. Light winds.</text>
                <text type="uv_alert">Sun protection 9:30am to 2:20pm, UV Index predicted to reach 5 [Moderate]</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2020-04-14T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-15T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-13T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-14T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Areas of fog in the morning. Sunny day. Light winds becoming northwesterly 15 to 20 km/h in the early afternoon then becoming light in the late afternoon.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2020-04-15T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-16T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-14T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-15T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Patchy morning fog. Mostly sunny day. Light winds.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2020-04-16T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-17T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-15T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-16T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Partly cloudy. Slight (20%) chance of a shower. Winds northwesterly and light increasing to 20 to 25 km/h during the morning then increasing to 25 to 35 km/h during the day.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="4" start-time-local="2020-04-17T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-18T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-16T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-17T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Mostly sunny. Winds northwesterly 15 to 20 km/h.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="5" start-time-local="2020-04-18T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-19T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-17T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-18T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Mostly sunny. Slight (20%) chance of a shower. Light winds.</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="6" start-time-local="2020-04-19T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-20T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-18T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-19T14:00:00Z">
                <text type="forecast">Partly cloudy. Slight (30%) chance of a shower. Light winds.</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
        <area aac="NSW_PT027" description="Canberra" type="location" parent-aac="NSW_ME006">
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2020-04-13T08:57:34+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-14T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-12T22:57:34Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-13T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">19</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
                <text type="probability_of_precipitation">0%</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="1" start-time-local="2020-04-14T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-15T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-13T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-14T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">10</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">4</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">23</element>
                <text type="precis">Possible early fog then sunny.</text>
                <text type="probability_of_precipitation">0%</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="2" start-time-local="2020-04-15T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-16T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-14T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-15T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">8</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">25</element>
                <text type="precis">Mostly sunny.</text>
                <text type="probability_of_precipitation">0%</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="3" start-time-local="2020-04-16T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-17T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-15T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-16T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">11</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">25</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
                <text type="probability_of_precipitation">20%</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="4" start-time-local="2020-04-17T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-18T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-16T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-17T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">11</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">20</element>
                <text type="precis">Mostly sunny.</text>
                <text type="probability_of_precipitation">10%</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="5" start-time-local="2020-04-18T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-19T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-17T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-18T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">4</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">19</element>
                <text type="precis">Mostly sunny.</text>
                <text type="probability_of_precipitation">20%</text>
            </forecast-period>
            <forecast-period index="6" start-time-local="2020-04-19T00:00:00+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-20T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-18T14:00:00Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-19T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="forecast_icon_code">3</element>
                <element type="precipitation_range">0 to 0.4 mm</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_minimum" units="Celsius">8</element>
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">19</element>
                <text type="precis">Partly cloudy.</text>
                <text type="probability_of_precipitation">30%</text>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
        <area aac="NSW_PT146" description="Tuggeranong" type="location" parent-aac="NSW_ME006">
            <forecast-period index="0" start-time-local="2020-04-13T08:57:34+10:00" end-time-local="2020-04-14T00:00:00+10:00" start-time-utc="2020-04-12T22:57:34Z" end-time-utc="2020-04-13T14:00:00Z">
                <element type="air_temperature_maximum" units="Celsius">19</element>
            </forecast-period>
        </area>
    </forecast>
```

To get the text:

> Forecast for the rest of Monday April 13 Some high cloud, clearing by
>   the afternoon. Light winds. Forecast for the rest of Tuesday April 14
>   Areas of fog in the morning. Sunny day. Light winds becoming
>   northwesterly 15 to 20 km/h in the early afternoon then becoming light
>   in the late afternoon. Forecast for the rest of Wednesday April 15
>   Patchy morning fog. Mostly sunny day. Light winds.
>   .... etc

I used:

```
<xsl:variable name ="cb" select="document('cb123.xml')"/>
<xsl:variable name = "canberra_date" select = "$cb/forecast/area[@aac='NSW_ME006']/forecast-period"/>
<b>Canberra Weather</b>
<br></br>
      <xsl:for-each select='$canberra_date'>
      <xsl:text>Forecast for the rest of </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(@start-time-local, '[F] [MNn] [D1]', 'en', (), ()) "/>
<br></br>
      <xsl:value-of select="text[@type='forecast']"/>
<br></br>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

Q1. How would I be able to get the text above and write it to a html as well as the temperatures inside the nodes:

```
/forecast/area[@aac='NSW_PT027']/forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_maximum'] and 
/forecast/area[@aac='NSW_PT027']/forecast-period/element[@type='air_temperature_minimum']
```

Q2. How would I do it so that it skips the first text in this loop? i.e. I don't want the "Forecast for the rest of Monday April 13, only starting at Tuesday April 14 as well as the corresponding temperatures?

Desired output:

```
> Forecast for Tuesday 14 April Areas of fog in the morning. Sunny day.
> Light winds becoming northwesterly 15 to 20 km/h in the early 
> afternoon then becoming light in the late afternoon. Min  4 Max 23
> 
> Forecast for Wednesday 15 April Patchy morning fog. Mostly sunny day.
> Light winds. Min  8 Max 25 ....
```

Something like this.. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way this could be done. Adapt the layout to what you need.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>Weather Forecast</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <b>Canberra Weather</b>
        <br/>
        <xsl:for-each select="forecast/area[@aac='NSW_ME006']/forecast-period[position()!=1]"> <!-- Skip first forecast-period -->
            <xsl:variable name="currentF" select="."/>
            <xsl:text>Forecast for the rest of </xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="format-dateTime(@start-time-local, '[F] [MNn] [D1]', 'en', (), ()) "/>
            <xsl:value-of select="text[@type='forecast']"/>
            <br/>
            Min <xsl:value-of select="//area[@parent-aac=$currentF/../@aac]/forecast-period[@start-time-local=$currentF/@start-time-local]/element[@type='air_temperature_minimum']"/>
            <br/>
            Max <xsl:value-of select="//area[@parent-aac=$currentF/../@aac]/forecast-period[@start-time-local=$currentF/@start-time-local]/element[@type='air_temperature_maximum']"/>
            <br/><br/>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

See it working here : https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/gVhDDzf

Comment: Seems to work, could I ask how exactly the //area that you used to select the text works? as well as what assigning currentF to a variable does? Thanks!

Comment: Also, if I were to exclude the last 3 entries of text, how would I do it?

Comment: The // goes back to the root node and then it selects area. Could also have written it as //forecast/area. In your for-each you are in the context of a forecast node, so you have to go back up the tree. To exclude the last 3 entries you could try adding a condition in the predicate of the for-each.